# Append $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Tags: php, url

Is it possilble to append some instructions to the end of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

So that it adds something like `?redirected=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
header("Location: ".$SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."?redirected=1");
die();
```

Comment: Note that `$SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is essentially user input here, and should probably be filtered before being included in an HTTP header.

Comment: @FrankFarmer but what could happen? It's not in a query or eval. Any double quotes are escaped in the string...

Comment: @FrankFarmer What are the negatives to using `$SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`? I keep hearing "If your ok with using it" being tossed around when it comes to the topic, but not alot of clarity as to why.

Comment: I wrote this as part of my answer but desided to remove that Part because the user could come from an external domain.

Comment: Something along the lines of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_header_injection or https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Open_redirect possibly

Answer (score 2):

the referer url may contains another params, so you have to do something like this.

```
<?php
  $refUrl = $SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

  if(strpos($refUrl,'?'))
      $refUrl .= '&redirect=1';
  else
      $refUrl .= '?redirect=1';

var_dump($refUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify every variable e.g. like this:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].="?redirected=1";
```